# Question about a confusing css specificity rule, (from the book SAMS Teach Yourself CSS in 24 Hours Second Ed.)

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

This is Rule 2 of 5 rules the book gives about how the browser determines which rule to apply in a conflict:

> An id selector is the second most specific [after inline style attribute]. If there is more than one id in the rule, the rule with greatest number of id selectors wins.

I really don’t understand what Rule 2 is talking about – it says “if there is more than one id in the **rule**” (which is singular). If there is only one rule, how is there a conflict or comparison(“the rule with greatest… wins”)? How can one rule have a differing number of id selectors, and where is the conflict if there is only one rule?

Can someone please expain this rule thoroughly? Thanks for helping, as I am trying to get the basics of web design down

Comment: [Interesting article](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) with regards to those books.

Comment: @alex: i wish every one would read this article

Answer (score 5):

A selector may have any number of ID selectors.

For example, `#id1 #id2` selects the element with the ID `id2` if it's a descendant of the element with the ID `id1`. It has two ID selectors, so it'll be more specific than, say, `#id2`, which just picks any element as long as it's the one with the ID `id2`, without any other conditions.

So between these two rules (assuming no inline styles):

```
#id1 #id2 { color: red; }
#id2 { color: blue; }
```

The first rule takes precedence, and the text in that element is colored red rather than blue, because the first rule has more ID selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, the selector with more id will take precedence:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
      Some text here
   </div>
</div>
```

now when i apply the css

```
#parent #child {
   background-color: red;
}

#parent div {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

the selector `#parent #child` will take precedence. because it is more specific than the second one. in this case the div will have a red background.

Comment: You mean `#parent #child` ;-)